# Split tunnel VPN with pptp-linux

Tags: debian, vpn, debian-squeeze, pptp, pptp-client

I have a client installed with `pptp-linux`.  I would like for it to be connected to a VPN (for VPN resources) as well as be connected to the internet for normal web browsing.  I know this is not as secure as totally VPN, but it is ok for this setup.

Currently I have a file called `settings` in `/etc/ppp/peers/settings` that has this:

```
pty "pptp $VPNHOSTNAME --nolaunchpppd --debug"
name $USERNAME
password $PASSWORD
remotename PPTP
require-mppe-128
require-mschap-v2
refuse-eap
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
noauth
debug
persist
maxfail 0
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute
usepeerdns
```

I fount [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/51340/setting-up-a-split-tunnel-vpn-pptp-client-on-ubuntu-10-04/) tutorial which tells how to do split tunnel with a GUI.
[image]

However is there a way to accomplish this same task using the command line or a line in `/etc/ppp/peers/settings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `defaultroute` and `replacedefaultroute` options from your settings file.  Then the VPN link will not become your default route.

Comment: hmm..  when I remove `defaultroute` or `replacedefaultroute` or both, I can't connect to the client anymore from another client.

Comment: Need moar details...  Client on what network?  Perhaps update your question with a route table or something useful?

Comment: There are three machines total.  One Windows machine, which has split tunneling enabled.  One ubuntu server that is the PPTP server.  And a debian machine, which this question is about.  When I do the above changes, I can't connect from the windows machine to the debian machine.  How do I print the route tables?